# How does the Android Gradle plugin handle conflicting resources in libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application project that depends on two Android libraries. The two Android libraries specify two resources with the same resource ID. In the old Ant build system, the priority of libraries was specified in a project.properties file, but such a file is not used in the Gradle build system.

Although the [Resource Merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) doc explains the priorities and merge process for resources that conflict between build types, product flavors, application projects, and library projects, it does not explain what occurs when two libraries (who have no common dependencies) are merged in a single project. During the merge process of the build process, how does the Android Gradle plugin determine which library's resource has a higher priority?

Comment: A Wang, did you find any solution?

Comment: I never found a solution. At the time when I was reading about the Gradle build system, this was more of a hypothetical question of mine. I had this thought because some of the projects I worked on used the same identifiers as some of the AOSP identifiers.

Comment: don't you think they are prioritized in the same way as for manifest? i.e. the library you mention on top in build.gradle file has more priority than it's below libs.

Comment: Is it always the order in build.gradle, though?  If this is how Gradle works, then that would be the answer.  Does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Hi @codevscolor. Yes, I have added an answer to the question. The Android documentation now states that the libraries that appear first in the build.gradle file will have priority.

Comment: Hi @Kevin! Yes, I have added an answer to the question. The documentation now explicitly states that libraries mentioned first in the dependencies block in the build.gradle file will have priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, looks like the Android developers documentation finally has an answer for us. I pulled this from https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations:

> The build tools merge resources from a library module with those of a dependent app module. If a given resource ID is defined in both modules, the resource from the app is used.
>
> **If conflicts occur between multiple AAR libraries, then the resource from the library listed first in the dependencies list (toward the top of the dependencies block) is used.**
>
> To avoid resource conflicts for common resource IDs, consider using a prefix or other consistent naming scheme that is unique to the module (or is unique across all project modules).

I bolded the relevant paragraph. It looks like that the order in which dependencies can appear in a Gradle dependencies block can affect the build process! This is a small thing to be wary of.

Answer (score 6):

There is not a way to specify a priority for the library's resources.

You can only setup the prefix in **your library** with

```
android {
  resourcePrefix 'mylib_'
}
```

Comment: Hello, maybe you know how make build would fail if any resource name is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

@Angela answer is great for solving your (and actually my) problem, for answering your problem according to how Android choose the right resource and what exactly the priority:

From the [resource merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging) part in the build process:

> The priority order is the following:
>
> BuildType -> Flavor -> main -> Dependencies.
>
> ...
>
> This means that if `src/main/res` has
>
> - `res/layout/foo.xml`
> - `res/layout-land/foo.xml`
>
> and `src/debug/res` has
>
> - `res/layout/foo.xml`
>
> Then the merged resource folder will contain the default `foo.xml` from
> `src/debug/res` but the landscape version from `src/main/res`